# POST request 404 (Not Found) - express-http-proxy

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, http-proxy

I'm trying to send a POST request to my api but it gives me following error:

[image]

I'm using `express-http-proxy` package for node to send request. Here is my code:

```
app.use('/api', proxy(targetUrl, {
  forwardPath: (req, res) => {
    return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
  }
}));
```

In my ReactJs application, I'm using `superagent` to pass my request and here is request creation code:

```
methods.forEach((method) =>
      this[method] = (path, data = {}, params = {}) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const request = superagent[method](formatUrl(path));
        request.set('Token', 'cb460084804cd40');

        if (params) {
          request.query(params);
        }

        if (__SERVER__ && req.get('cookie')) {
          request.set('cookie', req.get('cookie'));
        }

        if (data) {
          request.send(data);
        }
        console.log('sending: ', request);
        // request.end((err, { text } = {}) => {console.log('ended: ', text, err);});
        // reject();
        request.end((err, { text } = {}) => err ? reject(text || err) : resolve(text));
      }));
```

formatURL Function

```
function formatUrl(path) {
  const adjustedPath = path[0] !== '/' ? '/' + path : path;
  if (__SERVER__) {
    return 'https://' + config.apiHost + adjustedPath;
  }
  return '/api' + adjustedPath;
}
```

In addition to this, when I send GET request, it gives me following error:

[image]

*Also, when I try to send POST request on my live APIserver it gives **404 Not Found** error but if I try to send POST request on my localhost APIServer it gives **504 Gateway_Timeout** error.*

I am not confident about this behaviour. Therefore, need your help to find the problem. Thanks for your time in advance.

Comment: typically the 'unexpected token u' means you were trying to parse json but it was given 'undefined' instead. Have you done troubleshooting in the api forwarding function to make sure things are being set as you expect?